# Range of parameter values for a stability of a fixed point for this 2d map

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, stability-theory

So I am trying to do a linear stability analysis for a very simple 2d discrete system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_{n+1} &= y_{n}\\
y_{n+1} &= -\frac{x_{n}}{2} + ay_{n} + y_{n}^{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

One of the fixed points of this system is $(0,0)$ and I am interested in finding out the range of $a$ values in which this point is stable. I think there is something very wrong with what I am doing. The standard method of calculating eigenvalues of Jacobian gives me $a \in (-1.5, 1.5)$ but numerically I find that only between $(-0.5, 1.5)$ the point is stable and for $a\in (-1.5, -0.5)$ I numerically find that there exists a 2-cycle. I think this issue is not related to basin because I tried taking initial conditions quite close to $(0,0)$.

I would really appreciate if somebody comes up with the stability range and explain me what is wrong with my calculations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe us what numerical calculations you did?

Comment: I plotted a bifurcation diagram as a function of the parameter 'a'. It clearly shows two cycle before a < -0.5.

Comment: however the following matlab code converges to zero for a=-1.48, and diverges when a=-1.6:  `P = [1;1]*1e-6; for n=1:100 P = [0 1; -0.5 a]*P + [0;P(2)^3]; end`  Everything looks OK.

Comment: Can you add calculations to the question? It's _way_ easier to look at calculations that are already done and find what could went wrong.

Comment: @corbah: Please see this bifurcation diagram: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzH9PN_vFHAWR1Z3THE0TnRZOUE/view?usp=sharing]